# Nifi/Minifi: The rate of the dataflow is exceeding the provenance recording rate. Slowing down flow to accommodate

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm using `Nifi 1.7.0` to create a flow and then I convert it to `Minifi 0.5.0`. When I run the application, initially it runs well, but after awhile I'm getting this warning message:

```
    o.a.n.p.PersistentProvenanceRepository The rate of the dataflow is exceeding the provenance recording rate. Slowing down flow to accommodate.
```

I've already tried to change some parameters in `nifi.properties` file (changing the `nifi.provenance.repository.implementation` to `org.apache.nifi.provenance.WriteAheadProvenanceRepository` and increasing the
`nifi.provenance.repository.index.threads`), but the problem persists.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: You really need to look at doing an upgrade - you are 3 *years* behind.